# Converting from Editable to int in android

Tags: android

I want to convert the type `Editable` from an android `EditText` to the type integer to do maths operations on a user input number

I tried the following:

```
int x=(int)R2.getText().toString();
```

but it gives me an error of cannot convert a string to int.

Answer (score 35):

Fine, I got the answer:

```
int x = Integer.parseInt(R2.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 10):

Use parseInt(), like this -

```
intX = Integer.parseInt(myEditWidget.getText().toString());
```

The `getText()` method (which is inherited by your EditText widget from the `View()` class) returns an object of type `Editable` which must be converted to a String type before parseInt() can handle it.

Note that even if your EditText widget is defined with the `android:inputType="number"` you will want to catch the exception (`NumberFormatException`) that parseInt throws to make sure the value fits in an int!

Answer (score 5):

Try `Integer.ParseInteger(R2.getText())`

Comment: lol, I was just writing it down and refreshed the post and I found you wrote the same thing :)

Comment: It was something I knew, that doesn't happen too much :-D

Answer (score 1):

I used

```
int x = Integer.getInteger(R2.getText().toString());
```

`parseInteger` wouldn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

**My program works this way:**

```
int age = 0;

final EditText txt_age = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editTextAge);


String str_age = txt_age.getText().toString();

age = Integer.valueOf(str_age);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Koltin you can just add toString().toInt().
For example,

```
var someInt = some_edit_text.toString().toInt()
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Kotlin:**
Here we get a text from the *edt* that is an edit text.

```
val edt = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText)
val id = edt.text
```

To convert id to int:

```
id.toString().toInt()
```

Done!

Comment: This question has been already answered, and you are just duplicating other's answers. I am voting to close it.